# Installing cordova/phonegap application on windows 8.1 for all users

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova

I have well working application written in JS/angular compiling by Cordova, I can install it on Windows 8.1, but this app is installing for single user. What does it mean?

I have two user on my tablet/PC. When I install my app on first account it won't be installed on second account. I can't run this app from second account.

I am compiling application in MS Visual Studio 2015.

How can I install Cordova application for `all users`? Also for this users, who don't have administrator permissions. Is this possible? If yes, I would expect common folder for data exchange between all users on given device. Am I wrong?

I suppose, that there are some app configuration solutions or modification of installation Windows PowerShell Script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metro style applications are only installed on a per user basis by default.  The installer package for the app cannot change this. If you want to install a metro app for all users you have to use a special deployment tool called DISM.  More info on it here:

http://www.verboon.info/2012/02/managing-windows-8-metro-style-apps-with-dism/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will check this DISM, but it looks like it would work.